# Issue when trying to build and publish a Julia package that includes distributed parallelism

Tags: git, package, continuous-integration, julia, github-actions

I am very new to the process of publishing a Julia package through Git and GitHub.
For some reason, trying to register the following package failed: https://github.com/farhatlokmen/GapFilling.jl
I read guides such as this: https://juliaregistries.github.io/RegistryCI.jl/stable/private-registries/
and I am hoping for a more beginner friendly feedback.

Edit

I think the errors are related to a wrong implementation of distributed parallelism within a package. After testing, I found that skipping the parallelized functions and pushing the code to github gave no error.

Example of how I am calling distributed parallelism:

1/ functions file:

```
using Distributed
Distributed.addprocs(active_cpu_cores-1); 
@everywhere begin 
    using ParallelDataTransfer
    using GeoArrays
    
    @noinline function getZy(L1::Vector{Int64},
                            L2::Vector{Int64},
                            idx::Int64,
                            idy::Int64,
                            ImgBand::GeoArray{Float32, Array{Float32, 3}})
        
        l1=Float64[]
        @simd for p in 1:length(L1)
            b1 = (idx+L1[p])
            b2 = (idy+L2[p])
            if (b1>0) && (b2>0) && (b1<=size(ImgBand)[1]) && (b2<=size(ImgBand)[2]) 
                @inbounds Zy = ImgBand[b1,b2][1]
                @inbounds if (Zy>=0) && (Zy<1e+20)
                    push!(l1,Zy)  
                end
            end
        end 
        return l1
    end
end
```

2/ module file:

```
module MyModule

using GeoArrays
using DataFrames
using CSV
using Random
using StatsBase
using Metrics
using ProgressMeter 

using Distributed
using ParallelDataTransfer

export getZy

include("functions.jl")

end
```

Comment: What did you try? What happened?

Comment: For example, I followed a similar template to this guide: https://www.juliabloggers.com/tips-and-tricks-to-register-your-first-julia-package/, sith some minor differences like specifying a license and setting Git() instead of Git(; manifest=true, ssh=true) >> However, I received an automated email with some error messages https://github.com/farhatlokmen/GapFilling.jl/actions/runs/4413531787

Comment: Maybe this tutorial can also help you: https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/11-developing-julia-packages

Comment: The error output indicates that your code has syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you @StefanKarpinski , after more testing, I think the errors are attributed to a wrong implementation of distributed parallelism. I have edited my question

Comment: Thank you @Antonello for the link, it has helped me better understand how a julia package is built. I have edited my question.